# Integrate existing AWS Amplify project into Android project

Tags: android, aws-appsync, apollo-android

I found plenty of resources explaining how to create new AppSync projects and hooking them up to an Android project. But nothing on how to connect an existing AppSync project to an Android project.

I went through everything at https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/api as well as the AWS Console instructions, but nothing gets me closer to my objective, which is to connect the Android project to AppSync and have the relevant graphql and java files generated.

Is there anyone that had to do something similar that can guide me?

Comment: I believe if you open the **AppSync** console, you will find **API ID** there which you can pass to `amplify add api --apiId <ID goes here>` which skips setting up a new project and uses the existing API.